# Python - AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'train'

Tags: python, spyder

I have this error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'train' in my code below :

```
def main(unused_argv):
# Load training and eval data
image_ind = 10
svhn = sio.loadmat('train_32x32.mat')
# access to the dict
x_train = svhn['X']
y_train = svhn['y']
# show sample
plt.imshow(x_train[:,:,:,image_ind])
print(y_train[image_ind])

train_data = svhn.train.images  # Returns np.array
train_labels = np.asarray(svhn.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)

eval_data = sio.loadmat('test_32x32.mat')
# access to the dict
x_test = eval_data['X']
y_test = eval_data['y']
eval_dataSVHN = eval_data.test.images  # Returns np.array
eval_labels = np.asarray(eval_data.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)
```

when executing, I am getting the error:

```
train_data = svhn.train.images  # Returns np.array
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'train'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, do you not need to set the 'train' attribute? It doesn't look like you've done this, svhn['train']= "value"

Comment: What are the contents of the .mat file?

Comment: What does `svhn` print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong... `scipy.io.loadmat` [returns a dictionary](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html#scipy.io.loadmat), and base dictionaries don't have a "train" attribute. If there is a "train" variable in the matlab file, then it will be stored as dictionary key, so you can access it as `svhn['train']` (as opposed to `svhn.train`).