# Plot MINST dataset images returns AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'train'

Tags: python

I have this error: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'train'` in my code below :

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
mnist = tfds.load(name='mnist')

n_samples = 5
plt.figure(figsize=(n_samples * 2, 3))
for index in range(n_samples):
    plt.subplot(1, n_samples, index + 1)
   sample_image = mnist.train.images[index].reshape(28, 28)
    plt.imshow(sample_image, cmap="binary")
    plt.axis("off")

plt.show()
```

I'm trying to solve it as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50162858/15164196) but I get another error: `AttributeError: 'PrefetchDataset' object has no attribute 'images'`

```
sample_image = mnist['train'].images[index].reshape(28, 28)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With tensorflow v2 the use of tensorflow_datasets changed.

```
# Construct a tf.data.Dataset
train = tfds.load('mnist', split='train')

# Take 5 Images
train = train.take(5)

#Loop through youzr trainings images
for image, label in train:  
    print(image,label)
```

A more simpler solution is:

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data() 

# Input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# Channels go last for TensorFlow backend
x_train_reshaped = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
x_test_reshaped = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)


#ADDED print of images 
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
num_row = 2
num_col = 5
# plot images
fig, axes = plt.subplots(num_row, num_col, figsize=(1.5*num_col,2*num_row))

for i in range(10):
    ax = axes[i//num_col, i%num_col]
    ax.imshow(X_train[i], cmap='gray')
    ax.axis('off')
```

Comment: your code is run correctly but I plot images with this code it's right ?                                             n_samples = 5

plt.figure(figsize=(n_samples * 2, 3))
for index in range(n_samples):
    plt.subplot(1, n_samples, index + 1)
    sample_image = X_train[index]
    plt.imshow(sample_image, cmap="binary")
    plt.axis("off")

plt.show()

Comment: if i understand you correctly, you want to print the mnist images.  i added  how you may print the images to the second solution

Answer (score 0):

I believe `tfds.load` returns a dictionary object with key `tfds.Split` for `dataset` if `split=None` which is the default value. Have a look at the documentation - try playing with the `mnist` variable to figure out what object it is. I'm pretty sure what you are expecting it to have is just a layer beneath.

https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/load